# FusionCharts XT - Show value only when Mouse Over (MSLine2D Graph)

Tags: php, javascript, fusioncharts

I am trying to show values only when mouse over that point in the graph.
Is that possible?
Because I couldn't find any solution in the fusion charts Documentation..
This is my code:

```
public function Generate_MSChart($category, $data, $chart, $width, $height, $str_params=false) 
{ 
    $FC =  FusionCharts($chart, $width, $height);  
    $FC->enablePrintManager();
    $FC->setRenderer('javascript');

    // Default str params
    if ($str_params === false) {
        $strParam="bgColor=F4F4F6,F4F4F6;showValues=0;showBorder=0;palette=2;numvdivlines=10;drawanchors=0;divlinealpha=30;alternatehgridalpha=20;setadaptiveymin=1;";
    }

    // Set chart attributes 
    $FC->setChartParams($strParam);

    // Add category names
    foreach ($category as $ct) {
        $FC->addCategory($ct);
    }

    // Add data
    foreach ($data as $dtk => $dte) {
        $FC->addDataset($dtk, "");

        foreach ($dte as $elm) {
            $FC->addChartData($elm);
        }
    }

    return $FC;
}
```

As you can see I am using the ShowValues=0 Because my graph has alot of data in it.
and if im showing the values it won't be readable!

So what can I do to see the currect graph point value when mouseover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finds out the problem was the $strParam="drawanchors=0;"

When I've deleted it its started to work

Answer (score -1):

Setting "drawAnchors" to 0, the anchors are hidden and the tool tips for the data points will not be displayed and the links will not work either.

If you need to hide the anchors but still have tool tip and link, use: $strParam="anchorAlpha=0;"

Note that for JavaScript variant of FusionCharts, tooltip is shown even when anchors are hidden. You need to set the chart attribute `showTooltip="0"` to hide tooltips (but that would disable tooltip completely.)